# Where did the Sharing Options from nautilus go?

Tags: nautilus, file-sharing

Today I wanted to share trough my home network some files with my father's laptop who happens to be running windows.

I remember there was a 'Sharing Options' in nautilus when right clicking on a folder but I must have removed some packaged that removed it as well.

How can I restore it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This is how I resolved this:*

I had removed the `nautilus-share` package.

[image: Install via the software center]

Now, I have reinstalled it now and it works.